# Regenerating JAX-WS classes

Tags: java, netbeans, netbeans-8

Before a week ago I created a new Web service by using the option "New Web Service from WSDL".

Now the WSDL is updated, i.e. the classes headers were changed. How can I update my old Web service (7 days old) to use the new classes without removing and creating the web service from WSDL again. Is there any option like "Edit Web Service from WSDL" or "Regenerate WSDL" ?

Note: I'm using Netbeans as IDE.

Thanks in advanced

Comment: Are you using Maven with Netbeans ?

Answer (score 0):

I am going to assume you are using Maven inside Netbeans.

Look for the .wsdl file in the pom.xml is you don't know the name.
Simply copy the new countries.wsdl file over the old countries.wsdl in this case.

If the WSDL has new methods or removed, make the NewWebServiceFromWSDL class implement the interface specified in endpointInterface (xxx.BLAAPIPort in this case)

Remove this implements before you deploy.

Example Webservice Java code.

```
@WebService(serviceName = "APIPortService", portName = "APIPortSoap11", endpointInterface = "xxx.BLAAPIPort"
public class NewWebServiceFromWSDL {
```

FYI, plugin in Maven that was generated when you clicked "New Web Service from WSDL" :

```
<plugin>

        <groupId>org.jvnet.jax-ws-commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>jaxws-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
        <executions>
            <execution>
                <goals>
                    <goal>wsimport</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <wsdlFiles>
                        <wsdlFile>localhost_8080/ws/countries.wsdl</wsdlFile>
                    </wsdlFiles>
                    <vmArgs>
                        <vmArg>-Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all</vmArg>
                    </vmArgs>
                    <staleFile>${project.build.directory}/jaxws/stale/countries.stale</staleFile>
                </configuration>
                <id>wsimport-generate-countries</id>
                <phase>generate-sources</phase>
            </execution>
        </executions>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>javax.xml</groupId>
                <artifactId>webservices-api</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
        <configuration>
            <sourceDestDir>${project.build.directory}/generated-sources/jaxws-wsimport</sourceDestDir>
            <xnocompile>true</xnocompile>
            <verbose>true</verbose>
            <extension>true</extension>
            <catalog>${basedir}/src/jax-ws-catalog.xml</catalog>
        </configuration>
    </plugin>
```